# Big Commerce Cart Subtotal global variable name

Tags: global-variables, bigcommerce

I've asked Big Commerce on their community forum and in the help (chat) - I'm after the GLOBAL variable name for the cart subtotal. 
I need to include this in my invoice / tax receipt email. 
Currently I just add this to the bottom of my standard Invoice.

RECEIPT FOR DONATION

Received from: %%GLOBAL_ShipFullName%%
Amount: %%GLOBAL_SideCartTotalCost%%
Date: %%GLOBAL_DatePlaced%%

__
NB: the SideCartTotalCost doesn't survive as a variable through to the Invoice stage, so nothing is displayed in the email sent to purchasers.

Any thoughts or suggestion most welcome. I have a case open with Big Commerce but so far nothing has come from that.

Comment: Try using %%GLOBAL_value%%, hope it will work...

Comment: Perfect - thanks so much!

Comment: Always welcome..

Comment: Actually - turns out that wasn't a complete solution - if Tax is involved - it displays the tax as "value" - seems to be the last value to display in the cart.
 Any other candidates??